# Is subpoint an acceptable word?

Tags: grammaticality

MS Word likes to correct "subpoint"  to "sub point"

Is there anything grammatically wrong with "subpoint"?

Comment: Hi Falcondance!  What does your dictionary(ies) say?

Comment: See related threads, [_When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/), [_Is subaccount one word?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142700), [_Should I use hyphens with prefixes like “sub” and “semi”?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68642) and [_How do I spell “subdistrict”?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60404)

Comment: Acceptable to whom? Where? How is it being used? There is [no regulatory authority for English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25138), so whether a particular word or a particular spelling of a word will be accepted depends a great deal on the context. Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/299842/edit) your post to describe how you plan to use it, and for what audience.

Comment: This is trickier than it looks.  There are entries in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subpoint and http://www.yourdictionary.com/subpoint, but none in OED, M-W, or Free Dictionary.

Comment: What do you want it to mean? Can you give the context sentence?

Comment: Whether "subpoint" is correct or not, it's [commonly used, since about 1950](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+subpoint&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20subpoint%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: (MS Word likes to "correct" all sorts of things that it knows nothing about.)

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm not sure that that Ngram proves that 'subpoint' is *commonly* used; there's no frame of reference with which to compare. If we [plot it next to 'clause'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subpoint%2C+clause&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubpoint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclause%3B%2Cc0) for example, it suggests that it's barely used at all

Comment: "Subpoint" may not seem official or even very nice, but in context it's both useful and comprehensible. That's much more important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm collecting a handful of the comments into a CW post.  Feel free to modify.

To begin, here are two dictionaries which do have an entry for subpoint:

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subpoint)
- [Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/subpoint)

And here are three that do not:

- [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=subpoint&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch)
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/subpoint)
- [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subpoint)

Whether the word is in some dictionary or not, it is clearly being used by authors, as [this n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subpoint&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubpoint%3B%2Cc0) shows.

Finally, there have been other questions and answers on this ELU-SE that address similar, if not identical issues:

- [Should I use hyphens with prefixes like "sub" and "semi"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68642/13804)
- [When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/889/13804)
- [Is subaccount one word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/142700/13804)
- [How do I spell "subdistrict"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60404/13804)

From this, I think there is enough information for readers to draw their own conclusions.